# Unity Facebook 6.0 iOS Deep linking doesn't work

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm using unity facebook 6.0. My game was prepare for native iOS/Android.

I use FB. Feed to let a user share a feed to their wall and the problem is when I clicked to the feed it doesn't link me back to the game, instead it open the link url in the feed.

This problem happen to me only on iOS, in android it work fine.

I pretty sure that I follow almost the step in order to make a deep linking work.

In Facebook Setting,

- I had double check the bundle id to be the same.
- I set Single Sign On to YES
- I set Deep Linking to YES
- I borrow/set iPhone/iPad Store ID from another published game for this in-production game.

Maybe for more information for the issued, I try to send a request to a friend, and when a friend click on the request notification, it open up my game correctly. Can I assume from this case that the deep linking was working somehow?

Any suggestion would be appreciate,

Comment: Did you add the intent to the AndroidManifest.xml??? I am using 6.1beta and the FB.GetDeepLink is returning an empty string in android.. in iOS works fine..